# Simple script to encrypt some text in AWK

Tags: bash, awk

I need to write function in my Bash script to "encrypt" text.
I decided to use AWK to this function, but I have one problem.

Unfortunately I have no idea how can I find position of a character in string:

Example string:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz=,;.:-_+*?()!$&<>|ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789
```

And Result:

```
input a -> output 1
input b -> output 2
... 
input = -> output 27
...
input 8 -> output 79
input 9 -> output 80
...
```

Input will be always only one character.

Have You any Ideas how can I do something like this (preferably in AWK)?

Thanks, 
Gregory

Comment: So you want every `a` to be converted to `1`, every `b` to `2` and so forth? Give a sample input and how your output should look like.

Comment: How I show in my question:


My String:


abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz=,;.:-_+*?()!$&<>|ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789

When I input 'a' script should output 1

b ->2
 
c ->3

Comment: Ok, then `index()` is really the way to go. Note, though, that the unencryption won't be unique: `11` can come from either `aa` or `k`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `index` function to find the index of the substring within a string.

usage

```
index(string, substring)
```

eg

```
$ awk '{print index("hello world", "h") }'
1
$ awk '{print index("hello world", "e") }'
2
```

Comment: Its missing a final `'` and to work alone need a `BEGIN` like this: `awk 'BEGIN {print index("hello world", "h") }'`  You need some mechanism to handle `l` that you have three hits for, but `awk` gives only the first.

Comment: @Jotne my mistake. will correct that, thank you. As of `BEGIN` and `l` i wrote the snipet just to give an idea how `index` works. hoping OP would infer what he needs from the answer. :)